# Can you have two different camera buttons for two different image views on one view controller? (Swift 3)

Tags: ios

Here is my code below:  Basically I am trying to give the user an option to choose the camera button1 or choose from photo library button1.  Then depending on the button they press it adds to imageview1.  Then on the same view controller it is duplicated on the bottom half of the display with a camera button2 and a photo library button 2 that will go to the imageview2.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,    UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var ImageView1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ImageView2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!

var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var cameraImagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var imagePicked = 0
    var cameraPicked = 0

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        cameraImagePicker.delegate = self
        cameraImagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        cameraImagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        textField1.delegate = self
        textField2.delegate = self
}

  @IBAction func uploadImageBtnClick1(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary){
            print("Working")

            imagePicked = sender.tag

            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

            if imagePicked == 0{
                ImageView1.image = pickedImage
            } else if imagePicked == 1{
                ImageView2.image = pickedImage
            } else {

                print("Something went wrong")
            }
            if cameraPicked == 2 {
                ImageView1.image = pickedImage
            } else if cameraPicked == 3 {
                ImageView2.image = pickedImage
            }
        } else {

            print("Something went wrong")
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
   @IBAction func CameraButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

         cameraPicked = sender.tag

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
            print("working")


            self.present(cameraImagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the code you posted appears to generally do what you want, what exactly is your question or issue?

Comment: For some reason when I press camera button2 and take a photo it fills both imageViews.  The image seems to jump between both image views, changing every time I use the camera button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your use of two different variables to track which image view should be updated. Either reset both variables after updating an image view or use only one variable.

And there is no need for two `UIImagePickerController` instances.

Lastly, update the tags of all 4 buttons. For the two buttons that affect `ImageView1`, set their tag to 1. For the two buttons that affect `ImageView2`, set their tag to 2. Never use a tag of `0` since all views have a default tag of `0`.

BTW - name variables and functions with a leading lowercase letter. Only class and struct names should start with uppercase.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,    UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView2: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!

    var imagePicked = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField1.delegate = self
        textField2.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func uploadImageBtnClick1(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary){
            print("Working")

            imagePicked = sender.tag

            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func cameraButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
         if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
            print("working")

            imagePicked = sender.tag

            let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            if imagePicked == 1 {
                imageView1.image = pickedImage
            } else if imagePicked == 2 {
                imageView2.image = pickedImage
            } else {
                print("Something went wrong")
            }
        } else {
            print("Something went wrong")
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @rmaddy . The feedback is very important to me as I am a new developer and now I know for my future projects.  It works for me now.